# How can apose.cells be deployed in a serverless environment (Azure App Service)

Tags: c#, azure, aspose-cells

I need to create an API that users can call to create Excel spreadsheets. We use software called Apose.cells to create the spreadsheet. The API will be hosted in Azure App Services.

Can Aspose be used in such away? When I try and create a new workbook I get Aspose.Cells.CellsException: 'The file is corrupted. exception.

My intention, once the file is created is to then save it to Azure File storage account.

```
using (Workbook wkb = new Workbook())
{
   wkb.Worksheets.Add();
   var ws = wkb.Worksheets[0];
   ws.Cells[0, 0].Value = "Some data goes here";                    
   wkb.FileFormat = Aspose.Cells.FileFormatType.Xlsx;
   MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream();
   wkb.Save(s, SaveFormat.Xlsx);                   
   s.Position = 0;
}
```

Aspose.Cells.CellsException: 'The file is corrupted. exception.

Comment: I think it should be ok when using Aspose.Cells on Azure App Services. Seeing your exception part, it seems the issue is not about the environment. Could you give us more details about the exception, such as, complete stack trace. We are also not entirely certain which line of code causes the exception.

PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK Aspode.Cells is completely supported by Azure, though you can try looking at the system requirement in the below doc:

https://docs.aspose.com/display/cellsnet/System+Requirements

I would suggest you to look at the exception details and provide the logs here.Check this repo for complete samples:

https://github.com/aspose-cells/Aspose.Cells-for-.NET/blob/0f0ec0fac9561fd11accd2ce109717470b53654d/Examples/CSharp/Articles/ManageChartsAndShapes/AddCustomLabelsToDataPoints.cs

Hope it helps.